# Is there a way to automatically discard shapekey "offsets" for individual verts, based on their difference to basis?

Tags: modeling, scripting, objects, shape-keys

I know this is the sorta thing you'd usually code up with a simple script, but I'm absolutely python illiterate.

As far as I understand, shapekeys internally store their offset to basis when they're relative. However, over time I feel like a lot of my shapekeys have become "messy".
In the sense that a lot of vertices that aren't VISUALLY affected by a shapekey, still are moving a tiny amount, which within blender rarely causes issues but in other workspaces can cause minor normal shifts- Which is obnoxious at best.

I wonder if its possible to write a script that effectively goes through all shapekeys, and if a given vertex' "offset vector"(?) is less than a threshold, it gets clipped back down to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. I set the threshold to 0.1m so that means if the vertices differ by only less than 0.1m, then it will set it back to the same position as in basis. Feel free to change it to another value. It then goes on to iterate through all shape keys except the basis and compares all vertices to the basis using your threshold value.

```
import bpy

threshold = 0.1

obj = bpy.context.active_object
mesh = obj.data
basis_key = mesh.shape_keys.key_blocks[0]

for key in mesh.shape_keys.key_blocks[1:]: # loop through all shape keys except the basis
    for i, vert in enumerate(mesh.vertices): # loop through all vertices
        diff = key.data[i].co - basis_key.data[i].co
        if diff.length < threshold:
            key.data[i].co = basis_key.data[i].co
```